# Set application name in build.gradle for Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter application in which I add the following redirect scheme and appliaction name in app/build.gradle

`manifestPlaceholders = [ 'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'com.sgha.sdx_user_portal://login-callback', 'applicationName': 'com.sgha.sdx_user_portal.main']',`

But I get the following error

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.sgha.sdx_user_portal.main: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sgha.sdx_user_portal.main" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~ykU08tRWMZaLJ6MdKgUIEw==/com.sgha.sdx_user_portal-fCB4qyKngsCd56CC_1ADZQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~ykU08tRWMZaLJ6MdKgUIEw==/com.sgha.sdx_user_portal-fCB4qyKngsCd56CC_1ADZQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/~~ykU08tRWMZaLJ6MdKgUIEw==/com.sgha.sdx_user_portal-fCB4qyKngsCd56CC_1ADZQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]`

main.dart is my entry point. How should I set the application name? Without stting the application name in gradle I get an error saying that the applicaton name is not set:

```
/home/igharib/IdeaProjects/sdx-user-portal/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:5:9-42 Error:
Attribute application@name at AndroidManifest.xml:5:9-42 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <applicationName> is provided.
```

/home/igharib/IdeaProjects/sdx-user-portal/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
Validation failed, exiting

Answer (score -1):

this must be application's name

[image]

Comment: I have that but       title: 'Auth0 Demo', but if  remove the applicationName from the gradle I get another error as I added in question.